# Backbone.router: как выполнить controller повторно

Tags: backbone.js

Не могу понять как выполнить `controller` на одной и тоже же ссылке.
Есть `url` `cart/order`, если перейти на авторизованным, то появится окно авторизации, а если отказаться от нее, то ссылка останется `cart/order` и при попытке снова перейти по этой ссылке например из `<a href="#cart/order">Оформить</a>`
Ни чего не происходит.
Получается, либо надо вернуть назад, как это сделать? Или повторно запустить, как это сделать?

```
Controller.API = {
onOrder: function() {
                if ( login == true ) {
                     App.container.main.show(new Order());

                }else{
                    App.container.dialog.show(new  Login());
                    Data.user.on('change', function(args){
                         App.container.main.show(new Order());
                    });
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотри по ссылке. Это тебе поможет.
http://backbonejs.org/#Router-execute
Принцип какой - проверяешь в методе зарегистрирован пользователь или нет. Если нет - перенаправляешь на форму логина при этом запоминаешь текущий URL в переменной. Как только успешно авторизировался, берешь URL из переменной и перенаправляешь на нее.

Answer (score 0):

И если сильно надо перегрузить страницу то

```
document.location.reload(true);
```